# Generalized Union and Intersection by Induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Our teacher, told us to prove,

$$\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^c) $$

By induction. He told us that it has something to do with DeMorgan.

So my question is on knowing what's on the sets. I think that the left one has all the numbers to *n* except for the number 1, but in the right I get lost.

Can you explain how I could know the elements on the right-handed set? Also, if you could tell me another hint I would really thank you.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what the sets are ... you should be able to prove this for any set of sets $A_1$ through $A_n$. To do so, use the definitions you were given: what does it mean for some object to be an element of the complement of some set?  What does it mean for an object to be in the intersection of some sets?  And what does it mean for an object to be in the union of some sets?  Work out those definitions, and then it's pure logic from there (which at some point does involve DeMorgan, yes).

Comment: @Bram28 I think I got it, also I understood why both sets had just the number one, and reviewing my definitions I've come to an answer. I'm new in StackExchange, should I delete the question? Or if I got the answer what should I do?

Comment: To write "He told us that it has something to do with de Morgan." is to make me wonder whether you understand what you wrote. The identity to be proved _is_ de Morgan's law, applied to $n$ sets. Presumably you already know de Morgan's law applied to just two sets, saying $(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c.$ The identity to be proved says the same thing except that it involves more than two sets.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for answering! I hadn't fully understand the way Generalized Union worked but now I see how DeMorgan applies here and understood both side of the equation.

Comment: $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is defined by saying $$ \begin{align} & \quad x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i  \\ {} \\ & \text{if and only if } \\ & \text{for at least one $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$,} \\ {} \\ & \qquad x\in A_i. \end{align} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i\right)^c & = \left(\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \cap A_{n+1} \right)^c \\[8pt]
& = (B\cap A_{n+1})^c \\[8pt]
& = B^c \cup A_{n+1}^c & & \text{de Morgan} \\[8pt]
& = \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right)^c \cup A_{n+1}^c \\[8pt]
& = \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^c) \right) \cup A_{n+1}^c & & \text{by the induction hypothesis} \\[8pt]
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} (A_i^c)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$P(n)=\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^c) $$

Now for P(1) $A_1^c=A_1^c$

Let P(k) be true i.e. $\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i\right)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_i^c)$

Let $\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i \right)=B$

Now for P(k+1):

$\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i\right)^c=\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i\cap A_{k+1}\right)^c=(B \cap A_{k+1})^c=(B^c \cup A_{k+1}^c)=\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i \right)\cup A_{k+1}^c$

$=\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i^c \right)\cup A_{k+1}^c=\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i^c \right)$